# What sugar substitute behaves the most like sugar when baked or cooked?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm not a chemist. I'm looking for a sugar substitute that I can use for a cheesecake that behaves as much like sugar when cooked or baked. I've tried stevia (a plant based sweetener)but the filling takes longer to set and the crust doesn't hold up when cut. I'm looking for something that binds to fats the same way real sugar does.

Comment: How about some seasoned advice? https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/when-baking-what-works-well-as-a-sugar-substitute

Comment: Try saccharide derivatives like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylitol

Comment: Sugar alcohols like xylitols have disadvantage the bowel microflora can digest them and cause digestion troubles. some of them can have also undesired metabolical [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylitol#Adverse_effects) in bigger amount. In some food preparation context, sugar is hard to replace for this reason or another, e.g. the mass of sugar would be missing if replaced by highly sweetening artificial substances. Dozens grams of xylitol can make a feast for bowel bacteria and a bowel crisis for a person.